# US Citizen Student in UK Travel Restriction

Tags: uk, us-citizens, covid-19

Does the US European Novel Coronavirus travel ban restrict US Citizens from traveling back to the US from Europe or the UK?

Comment: I don't think there's any restriction on meat-eaters!

Comment: In essence, no - provided you can get a flight.

Comment: Since a US-Citizen is not a alien, the proclamation does not apply.

Comment: No, but you many flights have been cancelled, others are full of US citizens scrambling to get back to the US, you will be subject to screening upon arrival, and you should be asked to self-isolate for 2 weeks.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/dhs_wolf/status/1238608421915680768?s=21

Comment: @MarkJohnson there is no need to hyphenate "US citizen" when it's not being used attributively (for example as it is in the phrase "US-citizen spouse").